# Displaying gps satellite positions on skyplot

Tags: c#, gps, image, satellite-navigation

I have parsed ephemeris data in order to get the ECEF (or lat/long) positions of satellites visible above my current location.  I would love to display those locations in a sky plot in my C# program.
I added a picture box to my GUI and attempted to scale the x/y values to display but i don't believe the locations that are being displayed are relative to my current location.
Does anyone have any examples or sample code on how to do this?
I'm doing it in a C# winform.

```
private const double CENTER = 110;    //center of drawing (pixels)
private double SCALE_FACTOR = 89.0 / 90.0;  //pixels from 90deg to 0 on drawing
.
.
.
private void drawSatellitePos(int svPrn, double elevation, double azimuth)  //radians
{
    double r = 90.0 - ConvertRadiansToDeg(elevation);
    double theta = 90.0 - ConvertRadiansToDeg(azimuth);
    theta = ConvertDegToRadians(theta);             

    double xLocation = CENTER + SCALE_FACTOR * r * Math.Cos(theta);
    double yLocation = CENTER + SCALE_FACTOR * r * Math.Sin(theta);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}:  x: {1}   Y: {2}", svPrn, xLocation, yLocation);

    Point point = new Point((int)xLocation, (int)yLocation);
}
```

Comment: I would also like to be able to do this on a spinning 3D globe using WPF and C#. I hope somebody knows of a library or sample code to accomplish this.

Comment: If you can determine the ECEF position, then you can place it on Google Earth without too much trouble.  There are examples on how to interface w/ GE, and adding a point based on an x,y,z shouldn't be too hard.  I used GNSS project as my example code for parsing out ephemeris data, although i'm still struggling to verify that the data is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T.S. Kelso of celestrak.com has an excellent [series of articles](https://celestrak.org/columns/) on satellite tracking and orbital
coordinate systems.  [This article](https://celestrak.org/columns/v02n03/) explains how to convert satellite positions to
site-specific (topocentric) coordinates.  (You'll probably need to convert your
ephemeris  from ECEF coordinates (lat/long, rotates with earth) to ECI (inertial
coordinates, fixed with respect to the stars) to use Kelso's formulas.

The basic idea is to compute both the satellite and observer positions at a given
instant in ECI coordinates, then define the "east", "north", and "up" basis vectors
for the site-specific coordinate system at that instant (accounting for the earth's
oblateness), then convert the satellite position into look angles (azimuth and
elevation, or right ascension and declination) as seen from the observing site.

Comment: I think this may be a bit beyond my comprehension.  I'm not a smart guy after all.  I am looking at C/C++ code from the gnss project that has a function to determine elevation and azimuth based on my location and satellite ephemeris.  I'm hoping that it's not too tough to convert those values to a cartesian system.
I'm assuming since there was no comment on my methodology of placing the satellite on the picture box, that i am doing it in a sensible manner?

Comment: @Jason: Once you have elevation and azimuth as seen from your location, you're almost done!  The next step from there depends on what map projection you intend to use for your plots.  The simplest is probably to plot the positions in polar coordinates, with r = (90 deg - elevation), and theta = (90 deg - azimuth).  This gives you a plot with due north at the top, due south at the bottom, and the zenith at the center.  If you want a zoomed-in plot centered on a certain point of the sky, you'll need a more complicated projection (perhaps tangent plane).

Comment: my intention was to convert that to an x,y value since i don't really know how i would plot a theta value on the GUI.  
As i had mentioned before, my scaling seems to be a big concern since i'm really guestimating the max distance a satellite would be?  Am i thinking about it the wrong way?

Comment: @Jason: For the polar plot I described above, if the center is at pixel (x0, y0), with a scale factor of F pixels/degree, then x_sat = x0 + F*r*cos(theta), y_sat = y0 + F*r*sin(theta).  The observer-satellite distance doesn't matter, if you're just plotting satellite positions on a sky map.  It sounds like you might benefit from doing a bit of reading on map projections and how they are used.

Comment: now i feel like i am asking the dumbest question...
what am i using to base my pixels/degree? would it be my latitude degrees, or longitude degrees?  If it is the latitude, then i would assume that it is the number of pixels from my center point (90deg) to the horizon mark (0 deg).
I have made a real effort to understand how this is done. I think that the issue is having to understand multiple concepts from different sites and putting them together for a situation that works for me.

Comment: @Jason: At this point we're working in azimuth/elevation, not longitude/latitude.  But I think you've got the idea:  take the pixel difference between the horizon mark (0 deg elevation) and the center point (90 deg elevation), then divide by 90 deg to get a scale factor in pixels/degree.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm having points that are jumping way off the screen.  My image is 89 pixels from center to horizon.  The az/el are in radians, so i convert them to degrees, then perform the x_sat = x0 + F*r*cos(theta), y_sat = y0 + F*r*sin(theta).  While there are some that seem to plot well, there are others that are so far off they don't show on the screen.  what are the implications if my elevation is a negative value in radians?  Is it reasonable to take the absolute value of that?

Comment: @Jason: If the elevation is negative, the satellite is below the horizon and probably shouldn't be plotted at all.  Also, sin and cos expect their argument to be in radians, not degrees -- so it was perhaps a little sloppy of me to mix units the way I did in the previous comment. Hope you can work out the rest from there!